# SQL Select last occurrence of unique attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
   Date   | AttributeId | Score |
4/4/2013         1         0.64      
4/6/2013         2         0.35
4/6/2013         1         0.86
4/4/2013         5         0.34
4/4/2013         4         0.23
4/7/2013         3         0.54
4/8/2013         1         0.66
```

Can I construct a query in MS SQL so that I get only the last occurrence of a particular
AttributeID. From example above, the query would return this:

```
   Date   | AttributeId | Score |     
4/6/2013         2         0.35
4/4/2013         5         0.34
4/4/2013         4         0.23
4/7/2013         3         0.54
4/8/2013         1         0.66
```

If it helps, I know that there are only 5 AttributeIDs (1-5) and that they will not change.

For the moment I'm querying the last 15 records (and hoping that those records contain all of my 5 attributes), and then on the application level, extracting the latest scores for all 5 attributes.
Is there a better solution?

EDIT:
Also, if I have `Date`, `UserId`, `AttributeId` and `Score`, can I somehow group my results by `UserId`?
When I tried your answers, I saw that I only get the latest results, no matter which `UserId`.
I'm sorry guys, I should have mentioned `UserId` sooner

EDIT 2:
I need to get the latest scores by attribute for every user and average their scores over attributes.
The sample looks like this:

```
   Date   |  UserId  | AttributeId | Score |
4/4/2013        1           1         0.64      
4/6/2013        1           1         0.35
4/6/2013        2           1         0.86
4/4/2013        1           3         0.34
4/4/2013        2           3         0.23
4/7/2013        2           1         0.54
4/8/2013        1           5         0.69
4/4/2013        2           4         0.27
4/7/2013        2           2         0.54
4/9/2013        1           4         0.66
4/9/2013        2           2         0.58
4/10/2013       1           4         0.66
4/9/2013        1           2         0.33
4/11/2013       2           5         0.10
```

first result looks like this:

```
   Date   |  UserId  | AttributeId | Score |
4/6/2013        1           1         0.64      
4/9/2013        1           2         0.33
4/4/2013        1           3         0.34
4/10/2013       1           4         0.66
4/8/2013        1           5         0.69
4/7/2013        2           1         0.86
4/9/2013        2           2         0.58
4/4/2013        2           3         0.23
4/4/2013        2           4         0.27
4/11/2013       2           5         0.10
```

And the last result after averaging scores by `UserId`:

```
UserId | AverageScore |
   1           0.532     
   2           0.408
```

Comment: How many distinct attributes compared to the total number of records do you have?

Comment: and how many records?

Comment: Sorry, 5 attributes and about 1000 records

Comment: What do you mean by "group by userId"? Please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: @Quassnoi I've re-edited my question. Is this edit related to my first question, or do I move that to a new question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attributeId ORDER BY [date] DESC) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

If you have a fixed list of but a few attributes (or a table with them), this query might be more efficient:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    attribute a
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                [date], score
        FROM    score s
        WHERE   attributeId = a.id
        ORDER BY
                [date] DESC
        ) s
```

Create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX
        ix_score_attribute_date__score
ON      score (attributeId, date)
INCLUDE (score)
```

for this query to work fast.

**Update:**

To select an average of latest scores per user, use this:

```
SELECT  userId, AVG(score)
FROM    (
        SELECT  userId, score
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId, attributeId ORDER BY [date] DESC) rn
                FROM    score
                ) s
        WHERE   rn = 1
        ) q
GROUP BY
        userId
```

Comment: Just curious, is it possible to write a scalable query for this that works across platforms?

Comment: Strawberry: not an efficient one, no. You may use join the table to `SELECT attributeId, MAX(DATE)` but this won't handle duplicates and won't be efficient for but a few attributes.

Comment: Great solution @Quassnoi. Got a reference site or a place I can read a little more on the wizardry you typed up above? Just trying to understand what the query is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  [Date], AttributeId, Score,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AttributeId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  [Date], AttributeId, Score
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: If you have ties on `[date]`, `DENSE_RANK` will return duplicates which you may or may not want.

Comment: @Quassnoi that's exactly the purpose of the query. It handles duplicates.

Comment: your query will return several records for a single `attributeId` if the last records share `[Date]`. This, again, may or may not be desirable, I just wanted to mention that fact.